# how to wait until a dynamically included javascript file is properly loaded?

Tags: javascript, loading

I use an include function to dynamically include javascript files/headers/libraries.

The problem is that it seems loading the file happens in a multi-threaded way (tested on Chrome v102) and the js file is *not yet* loaded when I immetiately use functionnality after that.

Example with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var include_once = function(url) {
                /*
                [additional code to check if 'url' was already included]
                */
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = url;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            }
            
            include_once("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /*
            ok if I wait 'long enough' but is arbitrary
            */
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    console.log("ready (timeout)");
                });
            }, 10);
            
            /*
            how to wait until window.$ is defined?
            */
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("ready");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code will likely give you a `$ is not defined` error, and `ready (timeout)` will be logged to the console.

How can I make my script wait until `window.$ !== undefined` here ?

I tried `while(window.$ === undefined) {}` but it completely blocks the script and `$` is never defined.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#dynamically_importing_scripts

Comment: @mplungjan it *does* work with a timeout. Test it.

Comment: So add an eventListener to the script - more examples here: https://www.google.com/search?q=defer+script+until+other+script++has+loaded+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: `let script = document.createElement("script"); script.type = "text/javascript"; script.addEventListener("load", function() { console.log(\`${url} loaded\`) });  script.src = url; document.head.appendChild(script);`

Comment: You can easily achieve both targets with querySelector and promises https://jsfiddle.net/c7a1u6td/

Comment: @Christopher can you explain what the regexp does please?

Comment: It searches and escapes `"` with a backslash inside the url to avoid errors with invalid query selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can promisfy the loading process, by creating a promise on first script and then on the second script check if the promise is resolved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var isLoaded = new Promise((res,rej) => {
              function include_once(url) {
                  /*
                  [additional code to check if 'url' was already included]
                  */
                  var script = document.createElement("script");
                  script.type = "text/javascript";
                  script.onload = () => res()
                  script.onerror = () => rej()
                  script.src = url;
                  document.head.appendChild(script);
              }
              include_once("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js");
          })
          
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            isLoaded.then(() => {
              $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("ready");
            });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I never used `Promise` before but that's interesting- thanks.